# how to build a autoconf module and how to load that for compiling other program

Tags: kernel-modules

I am using our university's computer cluster which installed GNU autoconf 2.68. Now I need autoconf 2.69 to compile other programs. I don't have root privilege, so I want build my own autoconf module in my home directory. Could anybody help me on this, how to build autoconf module, and then how to load that module to compile other program, for example beagle library? Thanks very much!

Best regards

chongjing

Answer (score 0):

For autotools, as well as for any reasonably behaved open source software, it is just a matter of properly configuring the build system. For autotools (which use autotools for building themselves) it is the usual triplet

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

The trick is to tell the package to install itself somewhere where one has write access. Typically in a situation like yours it would be with:

```
$ configure --prefix=$HOME
```

which will create the usual FHS directories like `bin`, `etc`, `include`, `lib`, `share` in one's home directory. Make sure you add these to the appropriate environment variables to use them e.g. make sure that `~/bin` is in `PATH` before `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin` (or wherever the system-wide installation lives).